# Java Scrip For Loop condition issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a array `[ "apple", "apple-pie", "orange", "banana"]` and a value which is `apple`.

I want to loop the array to find which element includes the value, if the array element includes the value,show the array element. If the array element does not include the value, show the value.

My code looks fine, the only problem is, it shows the value several times when there are several array elements not included in the value. Is it possible to just show the value once whatever how many array elements are not included in the value (of course in the loop).

My code:

I just want `console.log("apple");` show *apple* once

```js
    let friute = [ "apple", "apple-pie", "orange", "banana"];

    for (i=0; i<friute.length; i++) {

        if (friute[i].includes("apple") ) {
            console.log( friute[i] )
        } else {

        console.log("apple");

        }  
    }
```

Comment: Your code does exactly what you write in your description that you want it to do: "if the array element includes the value,show the array element. If the array element does not include the value, show the value."

Comment: The result of my code is `apple、apple-pie、apple、apple`. The reslut i want is `apple、apple-pie、apple`

Comment: My answer below gives you the result you want. Please upvote and accept if you think it is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This modification to your code only writes apple the first time it encounters an array element that does not include apple.

This works by introducing a boolean variable `show` that is true in the beginning but set to false after the first time an array element did not include apple. By wrapping the log statement in an if-condition that checks whether `show` is true, apple is only printed once for all array elements that do not include apple.

```js
    let friute = [ "apple", "apple-pie", "orange", "banana"];
    let show = true;

    for (i=0; i<friute.length; i++) {

        if (friute[i].includes("apple") ) {
            console.log( friute[i] )
        } else {
            if (show) {
                console.log("apple");
                show = false;
            }
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the flag attribute

```
let friute = [ "apple", "apple-pie", "orange", "banana"];
let flag =0;
    for (i=0; i<friute.length; i++) {
        if (friute[i].includes("apple") ) {
            console.log( friute[i] )
        } else {
         if(flag===0) {
           console.log("apple");
           flag = 1;
          }      
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let index = friute.indexOf('apple');
console.log(index===-1 ?'apple':friute[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this my friend

```
let friute = [ "apple", "apple-pie", "orange", "banana"];
let appleIn = 0;
    for (i=0; i<friute.length; i++) {

        if (friute[i].includes("apple") ) {
            console.log( friute[i] )
        } else {
             if(appleIn ==0)
             console.log("apple");
             appleIn =1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: *try this my friend* isn't the best explanation you could write along with the provided code. Instead, explain what you have changed and why and what your code does and how it will solve the issue. Also placing your code in a code snippet would allow anyone to run it and see the results. Is that enough for a downvote? Absolutely. And btw, this applies to all other answers so far on this question.